# UsbDeviceConnection bulkTransfer returning more bytes than requested

Tags: android, usb

When using the Android USB method for bulk transfer of data, I've had the following problem:

```
int readAmt = 2;
numBytesRead = mConnection.bulkTransfer(mReadEndpoint, mReadBuffer, readAmt, timeoutMillis);
```

`numBytesRead` is now 4. Is this normal to receive more bytes than requested? I've always assumed with similar read methods it grabs n bytes *or less*.

Comment: Definitely, it is one weird behavior but the value might be overwritten by your array's length? especially that the default startIndex parameter is not there. Weird